# Castle IoC not registering service classes on server

Tags: .net, castle-windsor

I have been having an issue on my asp.net mvc web application when deployed to my server, but not when I am running it through visual studio.

Here is the error

Can't create component 'IndustrialRealEstate.Web.Controllers.ZoningController' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.'

The dependency in question is a service called ZoningService which is based off of a generic interface called IDataService.

Here is the code I am working with

Controller:

```
public class ZoningController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IDataService<ZoningWrapper> _zoningService;

    public ZoningController(IDataService<ZoningWrapper> service)
    {
        _zoningService = service;
    }
//functions
}
```

HasContext abstract class:

```
public abstract class HasContext
{
    private IREDbContext _ireDbContext;

    public IREDbContext IREDbContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ireDbContext != null)
                return _ireDbContext;

            _ireDbContext = new IREDbContext();
            return _ireDbContext;
        }
    }
}
```

IDataService Interface

```
public interface IDataService<T>
{
    T Get(string id);
    ICollection<T> GetAll();
    T Save(T dataWrapper);
    bool AlreadyExists(T dataWrapper);
    bool HasDependency(string id);
    bool Delete(string id);
}
```

Service:

```
public class ZoningService : HasContext, IDataService<ZoningWrapper>
{
//Implemented functions from the interface
}
```

ServiceInstaller:

```
public class ServicesInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<IDataService<ZoningWrapper>>().ImplementedBy<ZoningService>());
    }
}
```

Now, like I said this is functioning 100% when I run this through visual studio. I didnt realize there was a problem until I deployed to the server and the data wasnt coming through. Reading through the logs gave this particular message and I cant determine what the issue is.

If anyone has any insight, or a direction they can point me in I would greatly appreciate it.

Edit - Here is how the controllers are wired up

```
    public class ControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .BasedOn<BaseController>()
            .LifestylePerWebRequest()
            .Configure(x => x.Named(x.Implementation.FullName)));
        container.Register(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .BasedOn<Controller>()
            .LifestylePerWebRequest()
            .Configure(x => x.Named(x.Implementation.FullName)));
    }
}
```

Comment: How are controllers wired up to come from Windsor? Can you show the relevant code? Also, is there a reason that `IREDbContext` is not also controlled by Windsor?

Comment: Edited to add the controller installer.

As for the IREDbContext, I never thought of it to be honest. Im newish to castle.

Comment: Does `BaseController` inherit from `Controller`? If so, only need to register one convention or the other in your `ControllersInstaller`. Apart from that, your installer looks ok, they are registered with `PerWebRequest` LifeStyle which is correct. Do you have a custom `ControllerFactory` that resolves controllers from Windsor?

Comment: Did you have a chance to look into the problem? Was it solved?

Answer (score 0):

Did something similar to a WebAPI project.  Needed to add the following..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http.Dependencies;
using Castle.MicroKernel;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle;

namespace MyProject.DependencyInjection
{
    public class WindsorDependencyScope : IDependencyScope
    {
        private readonly IKernel container;
        private readonly IDisposable scope;

        public WindsorDependencyScope(IKernel container)
        {
            this.container = container;
            this.scope = container.BeginScope();
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return this.container.HasComponent(serviceType) ? this.container.Resolve(serviceType) : null;
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return this.container.ResolveAll(serviceType).Cast<object>();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.scope.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

... then add...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http.Dependencies;
using Castle.MicroKernel;

namespace MyProject.DependencyInjection
{
    internal class WindsorDependencyResolver : System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IKernel container;

        public WindsorDependencyResolver(IKernel container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            return new WindsorDependencyScope(this.container);
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return this.container.HasComponent(serviceType) ? this.container.Resolve(serviceType) : null;
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return this.container.ResolveAll(serviceType).Cast<object>();
        }

        public void Dispose() { }
    }
}
```

then modify the global.asax file...

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Castle.Windsor;
using Castle.Windsor.Installer;
using MyProject.DependencyInjection;

namespace MyProject
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            var container = new WindsorContainer();
            container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new WindsorDependencyResolver(container.Kernel);

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

Example of my installer...

```
using System.Web.Http;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration;
using Castle.Windsor;

namespace MyProject.DependencyInjection
{
    public class WindsorWebApiInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(
                Types.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<ApiController>().LifestyleScoped()
                , Component.For<MyProject.Database.IDataAccessMethods>().ImplementedBy<MyProject.Database.DataAccessMethods>().LifestylePerWebRequest()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The classes you have above help with Web API but not with MVC; controllers inherit from a different base class and the resolver for resolving dependencies is a different type (albeit performs a similar function)

Answer (score 0):

I would check if your installers all live in the same assembly, and check if the `container.Install` call matches the assembly scope that you need to cover. It is possible for example that the assembly containing the service installer is not loaded when you initialize you program. Perhaps logging what is installed would help you check whether the code runs at the program start.

---

Re: debugging this kind of problem:

It is quite hard to determine on the server what your container is missing. If you can reproduce the problem on a machine where debugging is possible I'd recommend using the [Castle Debugging views](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Debugger-views&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

Even better in my opinion, you could setup a test that checks whether all your dependencies can be resolved by Castle:

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class TestIOC
{
    public IWindsorContainer Target { get; set; }

    [SetUp()]
    public void before_all_tests()
    {
        Target = global::Main.Structure.IOC.Initialize();
    }

    public class GeneralTests : TestIOC
    {
        [Test()]
        public void should_never_have_a_potentially_misconfigured_component()
        {
            var host = (IDiagnosticsHost)Target.Kernel.GetSubSystem(SubSystemConstants.DiagnosticsKey);
            var diagnostics = host.GetDiagnostic<IPotentiallyMisconfiguredComponentsDiagnostic>();
            var misconfiguredHandlers = diagnostics.Inspect();

            if (misconfiguredHandlers.Any())
            {
                var message = new StringBuilder();
                var inspector = new DependencyInspector(message);
                foreach (IExposeDependencyInfo handler in misconfiguredHandlers)
                {
                    handler.ObtainDependencyDetails(inspector);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(message.ToString());
            }

            Assert.AreEqual(0, misconfiguredHandlers.Count());
        }
    }
}
```

This is straight from a test suite I use: if your IOC setup cannot resolve some elements it will write to the std output. In NUnit this translates into a failing test with some details on what is missing. The `global::Main.Structure.IOC.Initialize();` call returns the container after setup, which I use in the main code too.

Here is an example of the diagnostic output to help you find the missing configuration:

> ***** Main.Structure.TestIOC+GeneralTests.should_never_have_a_potentially_misconfigured_component
>
> 'Main.Configuration.NotificationManagementConfiguration' is waiting for
>   the following dependencies:
>   - Parameter 'daily_notification_time' which was not provided. Did you forget to set the dependency?

You could even add the code as a sanity check at the start of your program and log any error to fail as fast as possible.